# Youtube duration timing for range

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

**First off I would like to say  love the website**.

Okay i have youtube data api via javascript/ajax. I have a problem with duration coming up shorter than it actually is with a custom length based off a 1000ms timer. The skip to with onchange is also a value i used on the range bar. I do know this limited me to html5 users or so forth but I'd like to now show you what i have done. Remember I am asking how to avoid range stopping if i play it as is. Some youtube durations may come at 235 seconds or something i understand. If i'm correct this method would work smoothly flawlessly and does for 90% of songs. Once i retrieve duration on a few songs it's some odd reason not adjusting to the 1-100 range it's returning around 70 even closer to 90 on odd cases. What would that be? This is a real issue i would like to avoid dirty comments and help with the issue at hand.

Seconds on youtube may be 1-500 lets say. I want to round within 100 1-100 for range also keeping max without changing but allow it to be changed for stopping purposes.

```js
var count_this = 0;
var duration_bar;
var checkTime = function(max_value){
 count_this++;
 if(count_this <= max_value){
  lengthvalue.value=parseInt((count_this / max_value) * 100);
  duration_bar = setTimeout(function(){ checkTime(max_value); },1000);
 }
}

//then once youtube is loaded i use 

var onPlayerReady = function(event){
 duration = player_controller.getDuration();
}

//should i use buffering or something else here?

var onPlayerStateChange = function(event){
 if(event.data==YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING){ //would it be better here or what? }
 if(event.data==YT.PlayerState.PLAYING){
  checkTime(duration);
 }
 if(event.data==YT.PlayerState.PAUSED){ clearTimeout(duration_bar); }
 if(event.data==YT.PlayerState.ENDED){ count_this=0; lengthvalue.value=0; }
}

ducument.write('<li style="width:165px; list-style:none;">'+

'<input type="range" name="length" id="lengthvalue" class="range_media" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1" oninput="thisDur=duration; count_this=parseInt((this.value * thisDur) / 100); player_controller.seekTo(count_this, true);" onchange="thisDur=duration; count_this=parseInt((this.value * thisDur) / 100); player_controller.seekTo(count_this, true);"/>'+
               
'</li>');
```

This isn't a working snippet but a mock-up of what i have. I need a resolve in the math i used possibly. Review it for me it's mind blowing as it is.

Comment: Duration need to be set on playing i do believe ill let you know soon. If that was the issue...

Comment: Nope still need the fix...